# Render an image in svelteKit

Tags: node.js, path, svelte, sveltekit

I have been tearing my hair out over this one.

I have an image in $lib/assets/logos. How do i import it in a +page.server.svelte and a +page.svelte file.

The idea is to use it in an image html element tag.

Thanks

***UPDATE***
I cannot simply import it in +page.svelte

```js
<script>
    import logo from '$lib/assets/logos/logo.png'; // works
    import dynamicLogo from `$lib/assets/logos/${company}.png`; // does not work
</script>
<img class="h-32" src={logo} alt="logo" /> //works
<img class="h-32" src={dynamicLogo} alt="logo" /> //does not works
```

And use it since i do not know which logo to import. It is set at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean by "in an tag"?

Comment: Is there a `+page.server.svelte`? Maybe you're looking for this https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/assets#caching-and-inlining

Comment: Yes however, i do not know at compile time which asset i will like to import. SvelteKit does not allow string literals in import statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a [dynamic import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import) (which requires awaiting, e.g. via an `#await` block) or use a [glob import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) (with `eager: true`) to create a map of all logos which can be indexed with a dynamically created path.