# Sveltekit use a variable as image source

Tags: image, vite, sveltekit

I am using Sveltekit and typescript to build a website.
I am trying to display some images. The image source is saved in a json object.

I can easily display the image like this:

```
<img alt="The project logo" src="$lib/assets/images/test.jpg"style="width:50%;height:100%"/>
```

The json object has the file destination saved like this:
`j_obj.img_url`; where img_url equals: `$lib/assets/images/test.jpg`.

If I try to display the image the following way:

```
<img alt="The project logo" src={j_obj.img_url}style="width:50%;height:100%"/>
```

It does not work. Saying it can't find the image source.

Any idea how to display images, where the url is saved in an object?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75859475/546730